# Mocking current value of react ref in jest for shallow test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, ref

I am trying to mock `this.ref.current.value` as part of a test of a function in my React component.
Currently `current` is null because I am doing a shallow mount of my component. I am trying to find a way to mock what `current.value` returns for my ref so that I can test another part of the function, what the refs value is doesn't actually matter for this test.

Actual function:

```
copyDefinitionTarget = selectedInput => () => {
    // get and select the input value
    const copyText = this[`${selectedInput}`].current.value;

    // copy to clipboard
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText);
  };
```

Test code:

```
it('calls navigator.clipboard appropriately to copy the text in copyDefinitionTarget', () => {
    component = shallow(<Alert {...props} />);

    component
      .dive()
      .find('Item')
      .dive()
      .find('Button')
      .simulate('click');

    expect(navigator.clipboard.writeText).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Test failure:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

      50 |     // get and select the input value
    > 51 |     const copyText = this[`${selectedInput}`].current.value;
```

Is there any way to do this? I care about testing that navigator.clipboard was called not what it was called with.

Updating because I've changed my code to use `this.ref` instead of `stringRefName` 
Actual function:

```
copyDefinitionTarget = selectedInput => () => {
    // get and select the input value
    const copyText = selectedInput.current.value;
    // copy to clipboard
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText);
  };
```

Test code:

```
it('calls navigator.clipboard appropriately to copy the text in copyDefinitionTarget', () => {
    component = shallow(<Alert {...props} />);
instance = component.instance();

    // we are clicking on the first Alert Item
    // so mock that ref specifically
    instance.firstNameRef = {
      current: {
        value: 'stuff'
      }
    };

    component
      .dive()
      .find('Item')
      .dive()
      .find('Button')
      .simulate('click');

    expect(navigator.clipboard.writeText).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Function call:

```
<Item
 inputRef={this.firstNameRef}
 inputValue={`${realmName}`}
 copyDefinitionTarget={this.copyDefinitionTarget(this.firstNameRef)}
/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could go ahead and do something like this:

```
const component = shallow(<Alert {...props} />);
const selectedInput = 'ref';
component.instance()[selectedInput] = {
  current: {
    value: 'stuff'
  }
}
navigator.clipboard = {writeText: jest.fn()}
component
  .dive()
  .find('Item')
  .dive()
  .find('Button')
  .simulate('click');
expect(navigator.clipboard.writeText).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Note: I am not sure what kind of string **`selectedInput`** should be, you could pass any string which is appropriate according to your real component code.

Since the ref exists as a instance property on the component, you can just pass any object you wish as long as it looks like **`current.value`**, then you can replace the copy function with a mock, simulate the click and then see if **`writeText`** was called.

Comment: That worked, thanks! Just a note to anyone else using this the `const selectedInput = 'ref'`; `"ref"` needs to be whatever the ref is for the input you are targeting, in my case it was `firstNameRef`

Comment: So I updated my function call to use `this` instead of string so now onClick is `copyDefinitionTarget={this.copyDefinitionTarget(this.firstNameRef)}` and the mock is no longer working.

Do you know how I would need to update my test to get it to work again? I am trying a few different ways but it keeps saying the current value is back to being null
code: 
```
component.instance().firstNameRef = {
      current: {
        value: 'stuff'
      }
    };
```

Comment: @caraclarke what does the copyDefinitionTarget function look like now? And what does the test look like exactly with your changes. Could you update the question please?

Comment: updated the question with new code, it is back to giving me the original test failure message which was "Cannot read property 'value' of null" and when I try to console.log `selectedInput` for my test it says `{current: null}`

Comment: @caraclarke my guess would be that the child component is receiving the property before it was set externally in the test, you could try calling component.update() before attempting the click

Comment: I am still getting the same error failure, if I find the answer I'll post it here below

Answer (score 0):

Posting another approach that could be taken in case you are passing the actual ref instead of a string. I pulled getting the value from the ref into its own function and mocked that in my test

Actual code:

```
  // get the value from ref
  getRefValue = ref => ref.current.value;

  // copy value
  copyDefinitionTarget = selectedInput => () => {
    // get and select the input value
    const copyText = this.getRefValue(selectedInput);
    // copy to clipboard
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText);
  };
```

Test code:

```
it('calls navigator.clipboard appropriately to copy the text in copyDefinitionTarget', () => {
    component = shallow(<MetadataAlert {...props} />);
    instance = component.instance();

    jest.spyOn(instance, 'getRefValue').mockImplementationOnce(() => '');

    component
      .dive()
      .find('Item')
      .dive()
      .find('Button')
      .simulate('click');

    expect(navigator.clipboard.writeText).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```